# Initiate redirect 'mid page' in php?

Tags: php, html, redirect

I am trying to redirect a user to a 'success' page if the registration was successful. However, by this point, headers have already been sent so I can't just call `header()` directly.

What I did instead was put an included file (call it redirect.php) above the Doctype on the page:

```
// handle requested redirects
if (isset($_POST['redirect_to']))
{
$new_page = $_POST['redirect_to'];
header("Location: http://localhost/$new_page");
}
```

So if `$_POST['redirect_to']` is set, then header() can redirect to that page. Now the problem with this approach is that this `$_POST['']` variable is inside a function tasked with processing the user's registration, so of course, the form has already been submitted before the post variable is set, and therefore, `redirect.php` never gets to see the post variable.

Is there an easy way around this or am I making this harder than it needs to be?

Comment: I wouldn't bother with the redirect at all, just serve up the success message content within the context of that page you're on.

Comment: I think that you are just having a wrong concept of registration process , please check my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you havent mentioned AJAX my guess is that you are just having a wrong concept of registration process.

**Common registration process and structure:**

```
<?php
  if( !empty($_POST['registerme']) ){
    // do the registration process and possible errors STORE IN THE VARIABLE
    // lets say $errors, it could be an array of strings or anything you want

    // if registration process was succesfull, 
    // set $reg_suc to true otherwise to false
    if( $reg_suc ){
      header('Location: success.php');
      exit();
    }      
  }
?>

<?php
  if( !empty($errors) ){
    //there were some errors
    foreach( $errors as $error ) echo $error."<br>\n";
  }
?>
<form action="#" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="registerme" value="registerme">

  <input type="text" name="validateName" placeholder="name">
  <?php if( !empty($errors['validateName']) ) echo "Please correct this value";  ?>

  <!--
    //some more input fields
  -->

  <input type="submit" value="Register">

</form>
```

**EDIT:** This is of course common only for very simple applications with registration/login functionality, in MVC(P) architecture and similar achitectures this is usually created by a view using template file providing HTML template and a model/controller or model/presenter (in e.g. PHP) that are handling the registration/login process and possible error log and that are outputting results, errors and other data through the view back to user...